# allow access to certain php files in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

i have tried all the other similar questions and cant find a solution for this

Im running codeigniter and need to allow a few php files to be viewable and accessible (well they are infact compressed javascript files whaih are made by a compression library)

so basically i have this included on the page : 
/tmp/master_top_jsCBM1_1_applicant_js.php

this file does exist but i get a 404 Page Not Found

in the .htaccess i have this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|mobile|tmp|fonts|images|js|site|css|robots\.txt|^(.*).css|(.*).jpg|(.*).js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

notice that i have the 'tmp' folder accessible here and this is where all those php/javascript files are !

strangely this works on my local MAMP yet not on the server :(

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your .htaccess file is the cause of your problem. Check the `href` attribute of the `<link>` tag in your header. The value of the `href`should point to where your .js files are located. If this path is wrong you will get a 404 error meaning the `/path/to/the/file` does not exists

Comment: thanks ! yes the js file is in fact here :  /tmp/master_top_jsCBM1_1_applicant_js.php and that file is populated with everything its just not accessible (on the server only as locally its fine !)

Comment: You should probably not make your .php files publicly available for security reasons. But what you can do is include it in the file where you want it used by making use of the require_once('/path/to/file_name') function. I am hindering on changing the permissions of the folder on the server, but I would not do that.

Comment: thanks but do you know how to make php files available just for that folder /tmp ?

Comment: This is probably not allowed by your server admin or server settings. By doing what you've asked you'd expose your application to mallicious code injection, meaning that if a hacker comes across that .php file they would be able to edit it and execute it on your server. I cannot in good conscience recommend doing that

Comment: Why is your .js in a .php file though? Surely you can just have your .js files in your public assets directory?

Comment: because there is a compression engine taking lots of different js files and compressing them all together into one file - this happens for each different page so going to manually change things is not an option :(